# How to quantify which expression for a given mathematical quantity converges the fastest?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Which converges faster to $e$: $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$?

To check this, I thought of taking ratio of the two and taking limit as n goes to infinity,

Now the question is,

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}}{ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} =L$$

Now, what is 'L'? I think it is one. So, this idea seems inconclusive.

Comment: $L=1$ because both numerator and denominator converge to $e$.

Comment: I mean, would I get 'e' for less value of 'n' in series definition or limit definition or is both same

Comment: That has nothing to do with how fast both sequences converge. If you want to compare the speed of convergence then you'll have to consider something like $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{ e - \sum_{k=0}^{k=n} \frac{1}{k!}}{ e -(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}$.

Comment: You have to compare trailing parts for speed convergence i.e $speed(n)=u_n-\ell=O(n^p)$. In this case the series is way faster than the other definition.

Comment: @MartinR can you explain why you suggest that way?

Comment: Because this is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{{n \choose k}}{n^k} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k} < \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} < e$$

so $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ converges "faster".

Comment: very very very cool

Answer (score 5):

In fact, $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$ converges *much, much faster* than $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

- First, we can prove that the following inequality holds:

  $$ \frac{e}{2(n+1)} < \left| \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n - e \right| < \frac{e}{2n} $$

  So, in order to achieve the accuracy of $10^{-100}$, for instance, the value of $n$ should be as large as $\frac{e}{2}10^{100}$, which is roughly $1.35914 \times 10^{100} $.
- On the other hand, the inequality

  $$ \left| e - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!} < \frac{1}{n! n} $$

  shows that $n = 69$ is enough to achieve the accuracy of $10^{-100}$.

Comment: Funny, 69! was the highest before overflow 'error' (on he common TI30 calculator. New ones go far higher), so this is one tidbit I recalled, that 69! was of a magnitude of 10 to the hundredth power. Haven't thought about this in a long time.