# To find the function that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: functions

Suppose I've been given some function $V(x)$.

Is it always possible to find some function $g(x)$, such that the following conditions are satisfied :

$$V(x)=\sum_{i}^{n\ne\infty}C_i\{g(x)\}^i$$
$$\frac{dV(x)}{dx}=\sum_{j}^{k\ne\infty}A_j\{g(x)\}^j$$

For example, if $V(x)$ is a polynomial, then it is possible to satisfy the above conditions by setting $g(x)=x$. This is because $V'(x)$ would automatically be a polynomial, and thus can be expressed in terms of powers of $x$. As long as $V(x)$ has finite number of terms, this can be done.

Similarly if $V(x)$ is a linear combination of $e^{mx}$ with different values of $m$, we can choose $g(x)$ to be $e^x$, which satisfies the above conditions.

However, can this be done for every function $V(x)$ ? Is it always possible to find a $g(x)$ that satisfies the above conditions. Any hint on how I can prove this to be true, or false ?

Comment: Seems to me the question is "when can one generalize fourier/ taylor series?" aind since you seem to already know about [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494187/comparing-the-different-bases-for-representing-a-function). I suggest editing the question to the general one.

Comment: What does sum to $n$ *not* infinity mean?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational actually this is a different question from the previous one. In that question, I'm trying to figure out the best ( out of a given few ) bases to approximate a function. In this question I'm asking if for every V(x) can I always find some g(x) such that I can write both V(x) and V'(x) using the powers of g(x) and that this expansion must have a finite no. of terms. For example, if V(x)=$sech^2(x)$, then choosing g(x) to be $sech(x)$ or $tanh(x)$ does the job. If I had chosen $g(x)=x$ I would have infinite terms i.e. taylor series which is not allowed here.

Comment: @FShrike it means that there can only be a finite number of terms in the series expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it *always* possible? No. First of all, arbitrary functions are unlikely to be differentiable at all, much less satisfy your relationship. But even with sufficient regularity conditions on $V$, the answer remains "no".

Define $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n C_ix^i, Q(x) = \sum_{j=0}^k A_jx^j$, and your problem can be recast as finding $g$ such that $$\frac{d}{dx}P(g(x)) = Q(g(x))$$
or after applying the chain-rule,$$g'(x) = \frac{Q(g(x))}{P'(g(x))}$$
A little re-arranging
$$\frac{P'(g)}{Q(g)}dg = dx\\x = \int\frac{P'(g)}{Q(g)}dg$$

Since the integrand is a rational function, the method of partial fractions will reduce the integral into some elementary function involving rational and/or logarithmic terms. $g$ itself will be the inverse of that function.

But $V(x) = P(g(x))$, so for this to work $V$ must be some polynomial composed with the inverse of an elementary function involving rational and logarithmic terms. This is a very restricted class of functions, even in the space of all smooth functions.